# If $U$ and $W$ are subsets of $V$ and $U \subset W$ then $W^{\perp} \subset U^{\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $U$ and $W$ are subsets of $V$ and $U \subset W$ then $W^{\perp}
>  \subset U^{\perp}$

I am trying to understand the given proof: [image]

I absolutely do not understand how we arrive at the conclusion.

If we let $v \in V$ then for all $w \in W$ we have for some $v \in V$ the set $W^{\perp} = \{v \in V \mid \; \langle v, w \rangle = 0, \; \forall w \in W \}$. Since $U \subset W$, then for all $u \in U$ we have: $U^\perp = \{ v \in V \mid \; \langle v , u \rangle = 0 , \; \forall u \in U \}$ for the same $v \in V$.

Now my issue is with how this implies that $W^\perp \subset U^\perp$. If I talk about examples in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard basis then I can see the conclusion, but I do not see how to do this generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof starts with taking an arbitrary $v\in W^\bot$, and proves that $v\in U^\bot$.

Therefore, it proves the statement:

$$\forall v: v\in W^\bot\implies v\in U^\bot,$$ and this statement is, *by definition*, equivalent to the statement $W^\bot\subset U^\bot$.

Answer (score 1):

$x \in W^{\perp}$ means $ \langle x, y \rangle =0$ for all $y \in W$. If this is true then $ \langle x, y \rangle =0$ for all $y \in U$ because any element of $U$ is  also an element of $W$.  But what we proved is precisely the definition of $x \in U^{\perp}$

Answer (score 1):

To prove $W^\perp \subseteq U^\perp$, take $v\in W^\perp$. That is, $\langle v,w\rangle =0$ for all $w\in W$.

But $U$ is a subset of $W$ and so $\langle v,u\rangle =0$ for all $u\in U$. Thus by definition, $w\in U^\perp$.